# C++ search a tuple in map error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'

Tags: c++, stl

I always get this error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mt make_tuple<int,int>

int main(){
    map<tuple<int,int>,int> l;
    l[mt(5,4)] = 3;
    cout << l.count(mt(9,8));
}
```

1. What should I change to accept values from my file?
2. Where is the mistake?

```
int main(){
    map<tuple<int,int>,int> l;
    l[mt(5,4)] = 3;
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << l.count(mt(a,b));
}
```

Comment: The first three lines in your code sample contain enough bad practices to fill several posts. I suggest you unlearn this competitive programming taught BS, and quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `make_tuple` is having it deduce the tuple's type for you. If you invoke it explicitly specifying `<int, int>`, you prevent deduction from correctly taking place.

Just let `make_tuple` do its job and don't define macros just because you want to save a few keystrokes - you'll regret it.

```
int main(){
    std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, int> l;
    l[std::make_tuple(5,4)] = 3;
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << l.count(std::make_tuple(a,b));
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mzwIRwsgpYlA8U63)